# Parsing key-value pairs into DataFrame columns

Tags: python, performance, parsing, pandas

I have key-value pairs that are nested row-wise in a pandas Series. What's the most efficient/optimized way to split them into individual columns? (I can unzip and do transformations, but what's the *best* way?)

I do ***not*** know:

- Key names beforehand
- Number of keys in each record
- Order of keys in each record

The rows are a list of unicode strings. Once extracted, values will always be bigint.

Input:

```
parsedSeries.head()

0 [key1=774, key2=238]
1 [key1=524, key2=101, key3=848]
2 [key3=843]
3 [key1=232, key3=298, key2=457]
```

Expected output:

```
record   key1   key2   key3
0        774    238    NAN
1        524    101    848
2        NAN    NAN    843
3        232    457    298
```

Note that the input consists of lists containing Unicode strings of the format `u"X=Y"` where `X` is assumed to adhere to any required conventions for serving as the name of an attribute in Python, and `Y` can always be interpreted as an integer. For example, the following can be used to construct the sample data above:

```
pandas.Series([[u"key1=774", u"key2=238"],
               [u"key1=524", u"key2=101", u"key3=848"],
               [u"key3=843"],
               [u"key1=232", u"key3=298", u"key2=457"]])
```

Comment: What is the type of `parsedSeries.ix[0]`. Your example shows something that is `[key1=774, key2=238]`, but what is this? It can't be a list, is it a `dict`? Do you have a Series where each entry is a `dict`? Or is it organized as a sequence of 2-tuples, or what?

Comment: It's a list... In [81]: type(parsedSeries.ix[0]) Out[81]: list. I apply str.split to a df to create that list

Comment: Ok, then what is `type(parsedSeries.ix[0][0])`?

Comment: It's Unicode. Thanks!

Comment: So it's a list of Unicode strings such that every string is of the form `u"X=Y"` where `X` will be interpreted as a column name and `Y` as the value of that column for the current row? Is that correct? Is there a fixed data type for what `Y` will be? Can you also guarantee that `X` obeys proper Python attribute naming conventions? (For example, it's not a string with a dot (.) in it...)

Comment: Glad you probed. You're spot on. X will be interpreted as the col name that obeys naming conventions; Y will be a value, always a bigint.

Comment: I added this bit at the end, and I'll start from there to work on how I might solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" solution probably involves not finding yourself in this situation in the first place.  Most of the time when you have non-scalar quantities in a Series or DataFrame you've already taken a step in the wrong direction, because you can't really apply vector ops.

In any case, starting from your Series, you could do something like this:

```
>>> ds = [dict(w.split('=', 1) for w in x) for x in s]
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds)
  key1 key2 key3
0  774  238  NaN
1  524  101  848
2  NaN  NaN  843
3  232  457  298
```

Answer (score 1):

ok the final answer for you might differ based on how exact your example is.  Specifically, the regexes to parse the data might be adjusted.

Lets do some imoprts and set your datafile:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

f = StringIO("""0 [key1=774, key2=238]
1 [key1=524, key2=101, key3=848]
2 [key3=843]
3 [key1=232, key3=298, key2=457]""")
```

Now we're ready to start.  First just some regex magic to get a dict representation of your rows:

```
# get the dicts
rows = [dict(re.findall('(key[0-9]*)=([0-9]*)',l)) for l in f]
# convert values to ints
rows = [dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in row.items()) for row in rows]
rows
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 774, 'key2': 238},
 {'key1': 524, 'key2': 101, 'key3': 848},
 {'key3': 843},
 {'key1': 232, 'key2': 457, 'key3': 298}]
```

That was just regex but you are just about there:

```
pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Output:

```
  key1 key2 key3
0  774  238  NaN
1  524  101  848
2  NaN  NaN  843
3  232  457  298
```

Convert to a one-liner if you like but I leave it in two steps so you can tweak the regex to suit your actual data file.

Answer (score 1):

A very slight tweak to DSM's use of `from_records` for the sake of processing the values as integers rather than strings.

```
def key_to_int(split_vals):
    return (split_vals[0], int(split_vals[1]))

def dictify(row):
    return dict(key_to_int(elem.split("=")) for elem in row)

pandas.DataFrame.from_records(parsedSeries.map(dictify))
```

gives

```
Out[518]: 
   key1  key2  key3
0   774   238   NaN
1   524   101   848
2   NaN   NaN   843
3   232   457   298

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

where the values are integers (columns are still `float` type due to the `NaN` values and NumPy's continued lack of support for an integer NaN value).